# How to write the data in a block of a table line by line in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

Is there any way to write the data in a block of a table line by line in R?

I'll be grateful can someone find me a solution.
Thank you.

This is the input data in **tad**.

```
structure(list(gene = structure(c(4L, 7L, 2L, 10L, 1L, 9L, 6L, 
3L, 8L, 5L), .Label = c("ENSG00000065243", "ENSG00000084070", 
"ENSG00000127423", "ENSG00000135801", "ENSG00000163909", "ENSG00000174950", 
"ENSG00000183615", "ENSG00000197056", "ENSG00000203857", "ENSG00000204060"
), class = "factor"), domain = c(9L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 6L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the code I used.

```
colnames(tad)<-c("gene", "domain")
domain_result= aggregate(gene~domain, tad, paste, collapse = ",")
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYKmN.png)

I need this to be line by line. For example in the first row the data is like this.
**ENSG00000183615,ENSG00000204060,ENSG00000174950**
But I need it to be line by line.

Comment: Can you show an example of your input data and desired output data. I'm not clear what you want.

Comment: ENSG00000269405 119
ENSG00000177504 12
ENSG00000072506 129
ENSG00000029993 5
ENSG00000251192 62
ENSG00000268009 102
ENSG00000147003 85
ENSG00000102230 111
ENSG00000131725 59
ENSG00000147256 20
ENSG00000215301 72
ENSG00000230594 1
ENSG00000157514 82
ENSG00000198798 67
ENSG00000147130 174
ENSG00000260548 169
ENSG00000182220 61
ENSG00000204086 35
ENSG00000147246 45
ENSG00000267978 32
ENSG00000087842 60
ENSG00000147099 6
ENSG00000273696 144
ENSG00000205642 12
ENSG00000171659 168
ENSG00000187516 184
ENSG00000010404 32
ENSG00000102109 187
ENSG00000125363 116

Comment: This is my input data. The file name is chrmX_TAD.txt

Comment: `rm(list=ls())
TADfolder = '/media/mudith/HASTHI Films™/TADs/TAD_genes/TADgenes'
chrms = as.character(seq(1,22,1))
chrms = c(chrms, 'X')
#chrm = '1'
for (chrm in chrms){
  chrm_long = paste0("chrm", chrm)
  TADgenes = read.table(paste0(TADfolder, '/', chrm_long, '_TAD.txt'), header = F)
  # get subset of each TAD and then concatenate together
  # as block diagonal matrix
  # then get index, output y 
  colnames(TADgenes)<-c("gene", "domain")
  gene_domains= aggregate(gene~domain, TADgenes, paste, collapse = " ")
}
`

Comment: It's kind of messy so I add the code in the question

Comment: It find the gene names (eg: ENSG00000269405) with same ref. number (eg: 119) to one category and gives a table

Comment: I'm not clear what you want. You show what you get, can you also please show what you want to get? It would also help a lot if you would give us some sample input. Just a few rows of sample data.

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XKTcYTSCTF7BwvxHvrfEG0FEuPuFsbBM/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: Please find one of the input files from the above link

Comment: I need the results line by line not seperated by commas or anything else.

Comment: Most people don't want to go download data, copy it to their working directory, edit the filepaths, and read in who-knows-how-many rows and columns to understand what's going on in your question. You'll get help **much** faster if you share a little bit of data directly in the question, in a copy/pasteable format. 5-10 rows, only the 3 relevant columns, is great. `dput()` is a great command making a copy/pasteable version of an R object. Please enter `dput(droplevels(your_data[1:10, c("gene", "domain", "TADgenes")]))` in your console, and paste the result into the question.

Comment: Also, I'm asking for clarification on your output becuase I don't understand wha tyou mean. In your question, I don't know what mean by "one block". It seems like the entire point of the `aggregate` code is separate data by columns on a single line---so if that's *not* what you want, please help me understand what you *do* want by showing it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited it again. In the aggregate code it separate data in a single line. But I need it be separated line by line.

Comment: @MudithMMBc, still the output you want is not clear. What do you mean by line by line?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is what you can do to get the output you want in a way I understand it. Basically, what you want to do is `separate` the column `gene` into multiple `columns` while maintaining the `domain`. There is a function in `tidyr` called `separate_rows` that can do that.

```r
library(tidyr)

gene_domains_out <- separate_rows(gene_domains, gene,sep=",")
```

## Sample input Data

[image: head_gene]

Here is a `dput` of the image above

```r
#dput(head(gene_domains))
structure(list(domain = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), gene = c("ENSG00000230594,ENSG00000171155,ENSG00000224089,ENSG00000230347,ENSG00000236446,ENSG00000186471,ENSG00000101892,ENSG00000182890,ENSG00000232119,ENSG00000131721,ENSG00000101882,ENSG00000101883,ENSG00000242362,ENSG00000226685,ENSG00000125352,ENSG00000236126,ENSG00000237957,ENSG00000005893,ENSG00000125355,ENSG00000226600,ENSG00000125356,ENSG00000203989,ENSG00000226929,ENSG00000228517,ENSG00000177485,ENSG00000226023,ENSG00000236371,ENSG00000278646,ENSG00000158290", 
"ENSG00000176774,ENSG00000176746,ENSG00000232030,ENSG00000188408", 
"ENSG00000198205,ENSG00000215174,ENSG00000165591,ENSG00000198455,ENSG00000186787,ENSG00000204271,ENSG00000147059", 
"ENSG00000029993,ENSG00000166049,ENSG00000183862,ENSG00000102181,ENSG00000013619,ENSG00000130032,ENSG00000171100,ENSG00000160131,ENSG00000063601,ENSG00000147378,ENSG00000102195", 
"ENSG00000147099,ENSG00000067177,ENSG00000184388,ENSG00000225396,ENSG00000268994,ENSG00000198034,ENSG00000125931,ENSG00000269502,ENSG00000184911,ENSG00000275520", 
"ENSG00000102081,ENSG00000176988")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

## Sample output

[image: head_gene_output]

Here is a `dput` of the output data

```r
#dput(head(gene_domains_out))
structure(list(domain = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), gene = c("ENSG00000230594", 
"ENSG00000171155", "ENSG00000224089", "ENSG00000230347", "ENSG00000236446", 
"ENSG00000186471")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Hope that helps.